# Is it possible to call kotlin's js function with an interpolated string template?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

Right now, IntellJ is showing a red squiggly line saying: **Argument must be a string constant**

```
private fun fromEnv(name: String) {
    return js("process.env[${name}]") as Unit
}
```

I've searched but I have not found any similar question.

---

Solved by @alexey-romanov

It's just as simple as:

```
private fun fromEnv(name: String) {
    return js("process.env[${name}]") as Unit
}
```

which compiles to:

```
function fromEnv(name) {
  var tmp$;
  return typeof (tmp$ = process.env[name]) === 'string' ? tmp$ : throwCCE();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. But you can just use `name` in the code argument to `js`:

```
private fun fromEnv(name: String) {
     js("process.env[name]")
}
```

This example is pretty much the same as the use of the variable `o` in the [Inline Javascript](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#inline-javascript) section of documentation:

```
fun jsTypeOf(o: Any): String {
    return js("typeof o")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reference you can share with this answer?

Comment: Btw, @Alexey Romanov, removing the explicit cast shows a warning: Unsafe implicit cast from dynamic to String.

Comment: I've added the reference. Testing at https://try.kotlinlang.org/ I don't get a warning (but do get a wrong warning that `name` is unused), and don't see why it would be a cast to `String` anyway.